# SQL Server replication testing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

I'd like to write a sql script to do a basic smoke test to check that the replication setup on my server is correct.

I think a simple set of CRUD operations against the tables that are supposed to be replicated will achieve what I'm after and I imagine the workflow will look something like this:

1. `INSERT` a row into a replicated table in the publisher db
2. Wait for replication job to run?
3. Check the row exists in the table in the subscriber db

My question is, how do I do step 2? I think I can check when the relevant job was last executed by looking in the `msdb..sysjob*` tables, but I'm not sure this is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Good question Nick - transactional replication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For snapshot replication you can check indeed if *both* jobs have run (snapshot agent and distribution agent), but for merge and transactional you cannot since the agents run continously.

For transactional you can insert a tracer token and verify when the tracer token is marked as distributed to the subscriber, using [sp_posttracertoken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176091.aspx) and [sp_helptracertokenhistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187349.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Remus, tracer tokens do exactly what I need.